# Join tables with different data in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables like this

t1

```
id   value1
BMC  16
EC   22
LLU  60
MC   274
UHC  54
UHS  28
```

t2

```
id   value2
BMC  5
e900 4
EC   7
LLU  2
MC   1
```

How could I get this out put using sql server? I have used full outer join also. But its not gives me correct results

```
BMC  16   5
EC   22   7
LLU  60   2
MC   274  1
UHC  54   
UHS  28
e900      4
```

Here is my outer join, Its for two select statements. Not for tables. But those select statements gives above results (t1, t2)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(

SELECT b.EntityCode, COUNT('a') AS GroupCountUser1 FROM @TempUser a INNER JOIN OP_TB_TRN_Entity b
ON a.Entity=b.EntityID
GROUP BY b.EntityCode
) t1 

FULL OUTER JOIN 

(SELECT b.EntityCode, COUNT('a') AS GroupCountUser2 FROM @TempUser1 a INNER JOIN OP_TB_TRN_Entity b
ON a.Entity=b.EntityID
GROUP BY b.EntityCode) t2

ON t1.EntityCode = t2.EntityCode
```

Comment: [Show us what you've tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Also maybe post the incorrect results - it'll probably be possible to spot the issue from the output

Comment: You're using an inner join in the subqueries - is that on purpose?  And the schema you posted doesn't exactly fit the query...

Comment: Try using the `USING` join condition instead of `ON`.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are trying to do a `UNION` not a `JOIN`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you are forgetting to coalesce the IDs,  try

```
Select coalesce( A.Id, B.Id) id, 
    A.Value1, B.Value2
From A Full Join B On A.Id = B.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Select concat( t1.value1, t2.value2) as totalvalue

From t1 join t2 where t1.Id = t2.Id

If i understand what you're asking, this should help.